# Live Search using only PHP, JS

Tags: javascript, php

We just got homework to do live search, but we can't use AJAX or jQuery but neither we can use button to send a form. So is there any solution for this?

Comment: but as the post title says JS . you still have option to search it with javascript. instead of jQuery and ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function when the user types the key

Use JavaScript’s

`onkeyup=“function()”`

On the textbox that is taking the input and 
later in the function perform the required search(use php or js whatever is needed)

Comment: Oh, I forgot that onkeyup even exists. Yep that solved this problem, thanks! I guess I could search more about javascript.

Comment: As you are new, i would like to suggest you something. Whatever answer helped you solve the problem you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok, sorry I will remember that.

Comment: Don't use smart quotes, that will break the code. Also, inline handlers are as bad as `eval` - separate presentation from content, much better to attach handlers in Javascript instead.